# Merge two array with indexes

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have two array. I want to merge these two array with the same index.

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

And I want this after merge

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => 1
    [2] => b
    [0] => 2
    [1] => c
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Not possible, you can't have an array with duplicate keys: arrays simply don't work like that

Comment: Why not create a multi-dimensional array instead? `Array
(
    [0] => Array( [0] => a, [1] => 1),
    [1] => Array( [0] => b, [1] => 2),
    [2] => Array( [0] => c, [1] => 3)
)`

Comment: key is unique in array

Comment: @MarkBa Unclear

Answer (score 0):

in php you can do simply

```
$arr=array();
$arr_one=array('a','b','c');
$arr_two=array(1,2,3);

array_push($arr,$arr_one);
array_push($arr,$arr_two);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: And that gives the poster the index values that they want?

Comment: i dont think so its written in php